# dns domains, active directory domains and domain controller

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory, domain, windows-domain

I know these are big topics but i am just several questions i wish to clarify.

q1) are dns internet domains and active directory domains referring to the same thing or are related ?

Reason for asking the above is that if i have 2 small office in separate networks and I have bought 2 different domain names due to their different business nature.

e.g.

```
company1.com -- office 1
company2.com -- office 2
```

I wanted each office to have their own DC but will share the same AD database.

```
dc1.company1.com
dc1.company2.com
```

Can workstations in both network still join to the same active directory domain despite having different network domain names (company1.com, company2.com)

```
workstations in office 1 ---> dc1.company1.com ==\
                                                 --- join to the same AD domain
workstations in office 2 ---> dc2.company2.com ==/
```

Hence back to the original question, are internet domain and active directory domain referring to the same thing ? are they are just logical namings to group things together ?

Regards,
Noob

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no one has answered your question.

In regard to the link between active directory domain names and domain name space you purchase from a web hosting company, yes the two are related.   They are just logical naming to group things together, but with AD you can also use a domain name space that is not publicly available for use.   For example, server.local.

Networking device host names ending with .local are often employed in private networks, where they are resolved either via the multicast domain name service (mDNS) or local Domain Name System (DNS) servers. The implementation of both approaches on the same network can be problematic, however, so resolving such names via “unicast” DNS servers has fallen into disfavor as computers, printers and other devices supporting zero-configuration networking (zeroconf) have become increasingly common.

The IETF has designated the .local namespace to not be available for purchase and only used for local area networking.   So the main difference between domain names in AD and domain names on the public internet is AD domain names are not necessarily reachable by host name over the public internet.   It is possible to use an internet reachable host name (like you are planning on doing), but not required (and sometimes even frowned upon)

In short, yes, it is possible to have two seperate domain name spaces (company1.com, company2.com) and have them linked together over a WAN link.

The relationship between the two domains is what is called a transitive trust.  What follows is from TechNet and although the information refers to how Server 2003 functions, the same principals apply to Server 2012.

From Microsoft:

Transitivity determines whether a trust can be extended outside of the two domains with which it was formed. A transitive trust can be used to extend trust relationships with other domains; a non transitive trust can be used to deny trust relationships with other domains.

Each time you create a new domain in a forest, a two-way, transitive trust relationship is automatically created between the new domain and its parent domain. If child domains are added to the new domain, the trust path flows upward through the domain hierarchy extending the initial trust path created between the new domain and its parent domain. Transitive trust relationships flow upward through a domain tree as it is formed, creating transitive trusts between all domains in the domain tree.

Authentication requests follow these trust paths, so accounts from any domain in the forest can be authenticated by any other domain in the forest. With a single logon process, accounts with the proper permissions can access resources in any domain in the forest. The following figure shows that all domains in Tree 1 and Tree 2 have transitive trust relationships by default. As a result, users in Tree 1 can access resources in domains in Tree 2 and users in Tree 1 can access resources in Tree 2, when the proper permissions are assigned at the resource.

[image]

In addition to the default transitive trusts established in a Windows Server 2003 forest, by using the New Trust Wizard you can manually create the following transitive trusts.
Shortcut trust. A transitive trust between domains in the same domain tree or forest that is used to shorten the trust path in a large and complex domain tree or forest.

- **Forest trust.** A transitive trust between one forest root domain and another forest root domain.
- **Realm trust**. A transitive trust between an Active Directory domain and a Kerberos V5 realm.

A nontransitive trust is restricted to the two domains in the trust relationship and does not flow to any other domains in the forest. A nontransitive trust can be a two-way trust or a one-way trust.
Nontransitive trusts are one-way by default, although you can also create a two-way relationship by creating two one-way trusts. Nontransitive domain trusts are the only form of trust relationship possible between:
A Windows Server 2003 domain and a Windows NT domain

A Windows Server 2003 domain in one forest and a domain in another forest (when not joined by a forest trust)

By using the New Trust Wizard, you can manually create the following nontransitive trusts:

- **External trust**. A nontransitive trust created between a Windows Server 2003 domain and a Windows NT, Windows 2000, or Windows Server 2003 domain in another forest. When you upgrade a Windows NT domain to a Windows Server 2003 domain, all existing Windows NT trusts are preserved intact. All trust relationships between Windows Server 2003 domains and Windows NT domains are nontransitive.
- **Realm trust.** A nontransitive trust between an Active Directory domain and a Kerberos V5 realm.

**Trust Types**
Although all trusts enable authenticated access to resources, trusts can have different characteristics. The types of domains included in the trust relationship affect the type of trust that is created. For example, a trust between two child domains in different forests is always an external trust, but trusts between two Windows Server 2003 forest root domains can be either external trusts or forest trusts.

Two types of trusts are created automatically when you use the Active Directory Installation Wizard. Four other types of trusts can be manually created by using either the New Trust Wizard or the Netdom command-line tool.

**Automatic Trusts**
By default, two-way transitive trusts are automatically created when a new domain is added to a domain tree or forest root domain by using the Active Directory Installation Wizard. The two default trust types are parent-child trusts and tree-root trusts.

**Parent-child trust**
A parent-child trust relationship is established whenever a new domain is created in a tree. The Active Directory installation process automatically creates a trust relationship between the new domain and the domain that immediately precedes it in the namespace hierarchy (for example, corp.tailspintoys.com is created as the child of tailspintoys.com). The parent-child trust relationship has the following characteristics:
It can exist only between two domains in the same tree and namespace.

The parent domain is always trusted by the child domain.

It must be transitive and two-way. The bidirectional nature of transitive trust relationships allows the global directory information in Active Directory to replicate throughout the hierarchy.

**Tree-root trust**
A tree-root trust is established when you add a new domain tree to a forest. The Active Directory installation process automatically creates a trust relationship between the domain you are creating (the new tree root) and the forest root domain. A tree-root trust relationship has the following restrictions:
It can be established only between the roots of two trees in the same forest.

It must be transitive and two-way.

**Manual Trusts**
In Windows Server 2003 there are four trust types that must be created manually: shortcut trusts are used for optimization between domain trees in the same forest; external, realm, and forest trusts help provide interoperability with domains outside of the forest, with other forests, or with realms. These trust types must be created by using the New Trust Wizard or the Netdom command-line tool.

**Shortcut Trusts**
Shortcut trusts are one-way or two-way transitive trusts that can be used when administrators need to optimize the authentication process. Authentication requests must initially travel a trust path between domain trees. A trust path is the series of domain trust relationships that must be traversed in order to pass authentication requests between any two domains. In a complex forest, the time required to traverse the trust path can impact performance. You can significantly reduce this time by using shortcut trusts.
Shortcut trusts speed up logon and access times to resources in a domain that is deep within the hierarchy of another domain tree. The following figure illustrates trust relationships between two trees in a Windows Server 2003 forest.

--snip--

For further reading, check out the following links on TechNet

- [What Are Domain and Forest Trusts?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757352(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [How Domain and Forest Trusts Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Domain and Forest Trust Tools and Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756944(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Security Considerations for Trusts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755321(v=ws.10).aspx)